# IMDB web crawler - Scrapy - Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6, scrapy

```
import scrapy
from imdbscrape.items import MovieItem

class MovieSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'movie'
    allowed_domains = ['imdb.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.imdb.com/search/title?year=2017,2018&title_type=feature&sort=moviemeter,asc']

    def parse(self, response):
        urls = response.css('h3.lister-item-header > a::attr(href)').extract()
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=response.urljoin(url),callback=self.parse_movie)

        nextpg = response.css('div.desc > a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if nextpg:
            nextpg = response.urljoin(nextpg)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=nextpg,callback=self.parse)

    def parse_movie(self, response):
        item = MovieItem()
        item['title'] = self.getTitle(response)
        item['year'] = self.getYear(response)
        item['rating'] = self.getRating(response)
        item['genre'] = self.getGenre(response)
        item['director'] = self.getDirector(response)
        item['summary'] = self.getSummary(response)
        item['actors'] = self.getActors(response)
        yield item
```

I have wrote the above code for scraping all imdb movies from 2017 to till date. But this code only scrapes 100 movies. Please Help.

Comment: if my answer helped you, can you please mark it correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the issue is with

```
nextpg = response.css('div.desc > a::attr(href)').extract_first()
```

On this page
https://www.imdb.com/search/title?year=2017,2018&title_type=feature&sort=moviemeter,asc

the code for the next page link is this

```
<div class="desc">
    <span class="lister-current-first-item">1</span> to
    <span class="lister-current-last-item">50</span> of 24,842 titles
    <span class="ghost">|</span>
    <a href="?year=2017,2018&amp;title_type=feature&amp;sort=moviemeter,asc&amp;page=2&amp;ref_=adv_nxt" class="lister-page-next next-page" ref-marker="adv_nxt">Next »</a>
</div>
```

Your code grabs the href of the link with the anchor text Next >>

which is this

https://www.imdb.com/search/title?year=2017,2018&title_type=feature&sort=moviemeter,asc&page=2&ref_=adv_nxt

you go to that page and you scrape the next 50 movies

however the html in the div with a class of desc has TWO links in it. Not one like the first page.

The first link is the previous link, not the next link.

```
<div class="desc">
    <span class="lister-current-first-item">51</span> to
    <span class="lister-current-last-item">100</span> of 24,842 titles
    <span class="ghost">|</span> <a href="?year=2017,2018&amp;title_type=feature&amp;sort=moviemeter,asc&amp;page=1&amp;ref_=adv_prv" class="lister-page-prev prev-page" ref-marker="adv_nxt">« Previous</a>
    <span class="ghost">|</span> <a href="?year=2017,2018&amp;title_type=feature&amp;sort=moviemeter,asc&amp;page=3&amp;ref_=adv_nxt" class="lister-page-next next-page" ref-marker="adv_nxt">Next »</a>
</div>
```

What I would do is set a counter to 0.

Increment on a successful scrape.

If the counter is greater than 0 then grab the second link and goto that link and scrape the results on that page

If the counter is not greater than 0 then grab the first link and goto that and scrape the results on that page