# IMDB Movie Scraping gives blank csv using scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, export-to-csv

I am getting Blank csv, though its not showing any error in code.
It is unable to crawl through web page.

This is the code which I have written referring youtube:-

```
import scrapy

from Example.items import MovieItem

class ThirdSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "imdbtestspider"
allowed_domains = ["imdb.com"]
start_url = ('http://www.imdb.com/chart/top',)


  def parse(self,response):
    links = response.xpath('//tbody[@class="lister-list"]/tr/td[@class="titleColumn"]/a/@href').extract()
    i = 1
    for link in links:
        abs_url = response.urljoin(link)
        #
        url_next = '//*[@id="main"]/div/span/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr['+str(i)+']/td[3]/strong/text()'
        rating = response.xpath(url_next).extact()
        if (i <= len(link)):
            i=i+1
            yield scrapy.Request(abs_url, callback = self.parse_indetail, meta = {'rating': rating})

  def parse_indetail(self,response):
    item = MovieItem()
    #
    item['title'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="title_wrapper"])/h1/text()').extract[0][:-1]
    item['directors'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="credit_summary_items"]/span[@itemprop="director"]/a/span/text()').extract()[0]
    item['writers'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="credit_summary_items"]/span[@itemprop="creator"]/a/span/text()').extract()
    item['stars'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="credit_summary_items"]/span[@itemprop="actors"]/a/span/text()').extract()
    item['popularity'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="titleReviewBarSubItem"]/div/span/text()').extract()[2][21:-8]

    return item
```

This is output I am getting while running executing code with

`scrapy crawl imdbtestspider -o example.csv -t csv`

> 2019-01-17 18:44:34 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
>   2019-01-17 18:44:34 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages
>   (at 0 pag es/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52022970/imdb-web-crawler-scrapy-python) has a working code for what you are doing.
And also if you need more specific help please provide all of the code ( believe the `from Example.items` is your custom code?).

Comment: Also, start_url is a list so needs to be in square brackets, i.e. start_url = [www.abc.com, ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another way you might give a try with. I used css selector instead of xpath to make the script less verbose.

```
import scrapy

class ImbdsdpyderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'imbdspider'
    start_urls = ['http://www.imdb.com/chart/top']

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.css(".titleColumn a[href^='/title/']::attr(href)").extract():
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(link),callback=self.get_info)

    def get_info(self, response):
        item = {}
        title = response.css(".title_wrapper h1::text").extract_first()
        item['title'] = ' '.join(title.split()) if title else None
        item['directors'] = response.css(".credit_summary_item h4:contains('Director') ~ a::text").extract()
        item['writers'] = response.css(".credit_summary_item h4:contains('Writer') ~ a::text").extract()
        item['stars'] = response.css(".credit_summary_item h4:contains('Stars') ~ a::text").extract()
        popularity = response.css(".titleReviewBarSubItem:contains('Popularity') .subText::text").extract_first()
        item['popularity'] = ' '.join(popularity.split()).strip("(") if popularity else None
        item['rating'] = response.css(".ratingValue span::text").extract_first()
        yield item
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested you given `xpaths` i don't know they are mistakenly wrong or are actually wrong.

e.g;

```
xpath = //*="main"]/div/span/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr['+str(i)+']/td[3]/strong/text()

#There is not table when you reach at div[2]

//div[@class="title_wrapper"])/h1/text()    #here there is and error after `]` ) is bad syntax
```

Plus your xpaths are not yielding any results.

Answer (score 0):

As to why you are getting the error that says 0/pages crawled, despite not recreating your case, I have to assume that your method of page iteration is not building the page URLs correctly.

I'm having trouble understanding the use for creating the variable array of all the "follow links" and then using len to send them to the parse_indetail() but a couple things to note.

1. When your using "meta" to pass items from one function to the next, though you have the right idea, you are missing some the instantiation to the function your passing it to (you should also be using a standard naming convention for simplicity)

Should be something like this...

```
def parse(self,response):
    # If you are going to capture an item at the first request, you must instantiate
    # your items class
    item = MovieItem()
    ....
    # You seem to want to pass ratings to the next function for itimization, so
    # you make sure that you have it listed in your items.py file and you set it
    item[rating] = response.xpath(PATH).extact() # Why did you ad the url_next? huh?
    ....
    # Standard convention for passing meta using call back is like this, this way
    # allows you to pass multiple itemized item gets passed
    yield scrapy.Request(abs_url, callback = self.parse_indetail, meta = {'item': item})

  def parse_indetail(self,response):
    # Then you must initialize the meta again in the function your passing it to
    item = response.meta['item']
    # Then you can continue your scraping
```

2. You should not complicate the page iteration logic. You seem to get how it works but need help fine tuning this aspect. I have recreated you use case and optimized it.

```
#items.py file
import scrapy


class TestimbdItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    directors = scrapy.Field()
    writers = scrapy.Field()
    stars = scrapy.Field()
    popularity = scrapy.Field()
    rating = scrapy.Field()
```

```
# The spider file
import scrapy
from testimbd.items import TestimbdItem

class ImbdsdpyderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'imbdsdpyder'
    allowed_domains = ['imdb.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.imdb.com/chart/top']

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.css("td.titleColumn a::attr(href)").extract():
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(href),
                                 callback=self.parse_movie)

    def parse_movie(self, response):
        item = TestimbdItem()
        item['title'] = [ x.replace('\xa0', '')  for x in response.css(".title_wrapper h1::text").extract()][0]
        item['directors'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="credit_summary_item"]/h4[contains(., "Director")]/following-sibling::a/text()').extract()
        item['writers'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="credit_summary_item"]/h4[contains(., "Writers")]/following-sibling::a/text()').extract()
        item['stars'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="credit_summary_item"]/h4[contains(., "Stars")]/following-sibling::a/text()').extract()
        item['popularity'] = response.css(".titleReviewBarSubItem span.subText::text")[2].re('([0-9]+)')
        item['rating'] = response.css(".ratingValue span::text").extract_first()

        yield item
```

Notice two things:
Id the parse() function. All I'm doing here is using a for loop through the links, each instance in loop referred to href, and pass the urljoined href to the parser function.  Give your use case, this is more than enough. In a situation where you have the next page, it's just creating a variable for the "next" page somehow and callback to parse, it will keep doing that till it cant fint a "next" page.

Secondly, Use xpath only when in the HTML items have the same tagwith different content. This is more of a personal opinion but I tell people that xpath selectors is like scalpel and css selectors is like a butcher knife. You can get damn accurate with scalpel but it takes more time and in many cases may be just easier to go with CSS selector to get the same result.